# SteamGuard requires an email I no longer have access to

Tags: steam

I tried to login online to Steam but it says that I need to go to my email to activate SteamGuard. The problem is that the email it is set to was on an old outlook account on a computer I no longer have. I have no idea how to view the inbox of my old account (what website could i use?) I have not deleted the email account, just simply have no idea how to access it. :(

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about accessing an email account that the user does not remember how to access.

Comment: Generally, I'd recommend asking at SuperUser, but I suspect this is outside their purview.  Do you remember what the email address was?  If it was outlook, you should have a username at outlook.com you can try.

Comment: Sorry, this isn't the kind of question this site is really geared towards, but I suggest going to superuser.com to ask your question there

Comment: I think this is a good question if looked at from a perspective of "What do I do if I need to get into a Steam account where I no longer have access to the email?" rather than "How do I recover access to an email address?"

Comment: Superuser cant do anything here. Only valid way is to contact support and do their usual runabout with them.

Comment: SuperUser MIGHT be able to help if the old email address belonged to something accessible over the internet (eg. \@aol.com, \@hotmail.com, etc.).

Comment: What was the domain for your email address? Outlook is simply a client used to access the mail server. You may still be able to access the account via webmail.

Answer (score 7):

I quote from the Steam Support page: https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=4020-ALZM-5519&l=english#email

```
Please contact us if you have not received the verification email after 3 hours.
```

So, the only way you can reclaim your account is to ask them to change the email associated with Steam Guard (in particular, your Steam Account).
You can submit a support ticket here: https://support.steampowered.com/newticket.php?category=273
Just remember to include proof of ownership:

1. Your past passwords
2. Your email associated with Steam Guard
3. Any old Steam Guard codes
4. Any payment information (just not the full details)

Just a warning: Be prepared to wait around 3-5 days for a reply. Steam support (for some reason) takes a long time to process tickets.

Answer (score 0):

Contact steam support and go from there.